# Show only active (boolean) items in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my loop. On my region page I show all the cities with there activities, events etc

```
- @cities.each do |city|
    %li
     %h4.h6.icon_mappoint
      = link_to city.name, region_city_path(@region, city)
       %ul
         - city.events.each do |thing|
         %li
          = link_to event.name, region_city_event_path(@region, city, event)
       %ul
         - city.activities.each do |activity|
         %li
         = link_to activity.name, region_city_activity_path(@region, city, activity)
```

Each event and activity model has a attribute in the DB called active. (boolean). And want to show only the active events and activities in the view.

My controller looks like this now.

```
def show
    @region = Region.find(params[:id])
    @cities = @region.cities
end
```

Models

```
region has_many cities 
city has_many events, activities
```

How can I show only the active events, activities in the each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a scope to your `Event` and `Activity` models

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)
```

you can write your views like

```
city.events.active.each do |thing|
```

and

```
city.activities.active.each do |activity|
```

Comment: Thanks do you also know how i combine active events and activities in one variable like @events_activities ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `city.events.each` use `city.events.select { |x| x.active }.each`.

Comment: thanks. do you also know how i can combine the active events and activities in one each loop. By example store the all active items of each city in @active_items?